# ValidateXAML Failure on a TFS Build with a Silverlight 3 Project

Tags: silverlight, tfs, msbuild

I have a Silverlight 3 project which compiles and runs fine when compiled on a development machine.  On our TFS environment with Silverlight 3 and the Silverlight 3 SDK installed, I get the following error:

> C:\Users\tfsservice\AppData\Local\Temp\\Release\Sources\Source\Trunk\Themes\
>   UserDatesStyles.xaml(63,47,63,47):
>   error : The property 'Command' does
>   not exist on the type 'Button' in the
>   XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Mvvm.Input;assembly=Mvvm'.

More information: Command is an attached property on Button that is part of the Mvvm assembly in the Mvvm.Input namespace.

Am I missing something on my TFS server?  I would have thought that all I would require is the SDK.  If I edit this project and change the ValidateXAML element to false, the TFS server does compile properly.  However, this is obviously not the ideal situation.

Here is the XAML that causes it:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:MvvmFramework.Input;assembly=MvvmFramework"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Style x:Key="UserDatesStyle" TargetType="controls:UserDates">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:UserDates">
                    <Grid Height="600" Width="800" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="600">
                        <Button Content="Previous" 
      commands:CommandBinder.Command="{Binding PreviousPageCommand}" 
                                Margin="0,0,10,0" 
                                Style="{StaticResource PrevBtn}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I've heard of TFS Build having some issues when building Silverlight projects, although my team uses it all the time for the Silverlight Toolkit... if your development environment uses ValidateXaml, and check-ins are performed from such an environment, could you just make the call like you say to exclude XAML validation during official builds? We've had to do that when delay signing Silverlight apps, for instance, so the build can continue.

Comment: disabling ValidateXAML is possible but seems pretty hackish. I would prefer it ran and gave the same output as building in Visual Studio.  Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Same error if you login interactively to the build server under the build account, load the solution in Visual Studio, and build?

Comment: Also, double check that you have the RTM version of the Silverlight runtime & SDK installed on the build server.

Comment: Could you share the line from UserDatesStyles.xaml, with the attached property?

Comment: Hi Aidan. The build server has the RTM version, I even reinstalled.  And if I login and build interactively I get the same error.

Comment: Ray: judging from Aidens diagnosis, it seems that the latest version of that lib is perhaps not in your source control. What happens if you go to a completely new machine, get the project, and build there?

Comment: the version of the library is inconsequential because the MVVM assembly is not a reference via a binary reference but is a project in my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it on our solution... drove me nuts, we could get away with disabling xaml validation on the build server by passing /property:ValidateXaml=false to our build script. However it became a showstopper when we couldn’t build the project in blend. Blend doesn’t follow the same build process as VS, perhaps it just shells out to msbuild.

I added this to Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets just above the call to ValidateXaml:

```
    <Message Text="--------------- Start: Build Hack -------------------------" />
    <Message Text="ReferenceAssemblies: @(ReferencePath);@(InferredReference->'$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)\%(Identity)')" />
    <Message Text="ProjectAssemblies: @(BuiltProjectOutputGroupKeyOutput)" />
    <Message Text="SilverlightPages: @(Page)" />
    <Message Text="SilverlightApplications: @(ApplicationDefinition)" />
    <Message Text="ProjectPath: $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" />
    <Message Text="AssemblyName: $(AssemblyName)" />
    <Message Text="OutputPath: $(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <Message Text="ShouldThrow: $(ThrowErrorsInValidation)" />
    <Message Text="TargetFrameworkDirectory: $(TargetFrameworkDirectory)" />
    <Message Text="TargetFrameworkSDKDirectory: $(TargetFrameworkSDKDirectory)" />
    <Message Text="--------------- End: Build Hack -------------------------" />
```

... it looked like the ReferenceAssemblies were not correctly pulling in the correct references to the other silverlight projects, ValidateXaml seems to create an app domain and load in all those references to check if the types exist.... Anyway cut a long story short ValidateXaml wasnt getting passed the correct references as noted in visual studio thus we suspect it failed.

We believed it to be something corrupt in our configuration, we fixed it in the end by simply removing all offending projects getting the build to run from the cmd line (i.e. msbuild.exe) and VS, then adding each project back. After it was all done we noticed some differences in the .sln, the problem code had a strange 'postProject' ProjectSection under one of our Silverlight projects.... but its largely one of those 'you'll never really know', the .csproj’s seemed to be the same.

Remove the projects and add them back, worked for us. We suspect a corrupt solution file.

Comment: Awesome, would mark yours as the answer, but SO won't let me for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familar with Silverlight development, but I do have the latest Visual Studio 2008 SP1, Silverlight 3 [Runtime](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/), [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2050e580-f1d5-4040-bb09-e6185591b6b5&displaylang=en), [Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=9442b0f2-7465-417a-88f3-5e7b5409e9dd) and [Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight) installed and I do not have an **Mvvm.dll** anywhere on my machine.

This looks like a 3rd party dll, yours or someone elses, that is missing from the build server.

Where is the file referenced on the development machine that successfully builds?

It may be that will give a clue to the missing piece of the stack that needs to be installed, or added to a shared location that can be referenced from the project when pulled down on the build server.

Comment: Yes it is a custom DLL. That is the problem. My dll is referenced and WORKS but does not build in TFS.

Comment: It certainly sounds like a dependency issue, maybe not specifically the MVVM.dll, but related to the MVVM.dll.  It might be worth opening the MVVM.dll using Reflector on the build server and review its references.  If Reflector can't resolve the dependency, it will let you know.  Then that missing dependency, if any, is what needs to be installed, or referenced as a shared assembly in a shared location.

Comment: You've misunderstood. There is nothing wrong with the code, the application compiles and works fine on machines other than the build server.

Comment: I don't think he's misunderstood.  It looks like your build server doesn't have access to that assembly.  Is it precompiled or referenced as a project in your solution?  If it's precompiled, is the DLL checked into source control?   If it's precompiled and checked into source control is it in the same branch in your source control tree that is downloaded when the build runs?

Comment: Also, if you are referencing this Mvvm.dll from the GAC on your local machines, it would need to be GAC'd on the build server as well.

Comment: Ray, please post the errors section from your build log (everything after the words "Build FAILED".  If you scroll way to the bottom, this will be the last few dozen lines or so.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

The Build is fine in Visual Studio but within Team Build there are errors. I know the Xaml is valid and the Assembly the type is coming from is properly referenced and built before project with the problematic xaml validation.

I believe this is a bug with the ValidateXaml target in the C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets file or maybe the target is being called too early before everything is fully built.

I dunno.

I ended up changing the  property in the csproj file to false and although Team Build reports a ton of Validation errors it compiles and runs fine.